# What is the English equivalent for "для особо одарённых"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, word-usage, translation

There is a steady expression in Russian: "для особо одарённых". It can be used in such context:

> Повторяю для особо одарённых...

Straight translation is "I repeat for the gifted". But in general it highlights (on the contrary) the lack of talent or even the stupidity of the one for whom they repeat. So it is a kind of irony.
Is there a correct English equivalent for this (to use both spoken and written)? Or maybe for example the phrase "I repeat for outstandingly gifted students..." can convey the irony?

Comment: the thing is that if they found you explanations of what this mean insufficient there’s a risk you’d be downvoted. If you believe that this question is totally fine to be just migrated - just let me know, I’ll do it immediately

Comment: @shabunc I don't think it is *totally* fine, but I want to know if there is an equivalent. So let's migrate it!

Comment: This link has several dozen ways to call someone stupid: https://www.cartalk.com/radio/letter/alternative-ways-calling-someone-stupid . They are all ironic. You could say, "Let me explain this if you're a few french fries short of a Happy Meal." Or "Here's another way to explain it if your mind wandered and never came back."

Comment: @rajah9 Thanks, took into account.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a translation request from Russian.

Comment: There is also ‘preaching to the converted’ and ‘casting pearls before swine’. I’m not sure that implying that one’s students are idiots is the greatest teaching strategy, these days...

Comment: Any instructor could say the translation whilst stomping one foot and be fine in America. [Foot stomper](https://www.careeredlounge.com/topic/100177/122298)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would simply translate literally, "... for outstandingly gifted students." The reader will instantly get the irony.

Comment: I think that anything can sound ironic if the appropriate tone, and facial gestures are added. If I were to suggest an improvement, it would be ""And for the mentally gifted among you..." with emphasis on "mentally". I say this as "mental" is an informal adjective for "insane" or "having mental problems/disadvantages" and this carries through and specifies in the adverb.

Comment: @Greybeard I think you should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Greybeard : Oh, it was just a quick answer of mine on the Russian SE, before the question was migrated by the admin together with my answer. I simply wanted to suggest that there is possibly no direct established equivalent in the English language and that a more or less literal translation will work in most contexts. The OP even edited his question by adding the phrase suggested in my answer.

Comment: I would definitely *not* put emphasis on "mentally". That's too on-the-nose and also just plain rude. If anything I would *omit* it altogether, as indeed the original actually does. Mitsuko's suggestion is quite fine in that regard.

Comment: @RegDwigнt : Yes, the original Russian phrase is meant to be humorous, not on-the-nose, so a correct English translation should be humorous either.

Comment: @RegDwigнt  1. One can be "gifted" in many ways - it does no harm to specify. 2. All irony has an aspect of rudeness about it as the speaker is here, in essence, referring to some as "stupid". 3. It will depend on the speaker's relationship with the audience - the context seems to imply that it is informal.

Comment: As far as I know, the most common context in which the original Russian phrase is used is this: a lecturer explains something, and then a student asks a stupid question about the very basics of what has just been explained. So the lecturer reacts in a humorous way, "All right, and now let me explain such a difficult nuance to the most gifted of you."

Comment: I have to note that this idiom is a thinly veiled insult. While in the past professors could use it in the classroom, nowadays they can get in hot water for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this phrase can be used in multiple contexts and not specifically to point at someone's lack of intelligence. For example:

> Для особо одаренных - автобус отъезжает завтра в 8 утра

This can be used as a poke towards a person or group of people who are known to be tardy and make sure they get to the bus on time.

Similarly, it can be used in other contexts and in spoken language isn't normally considered offensive. Often it's used simply to emphasize the importance of 
 what's been said.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of what the equivalent expression is in English.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most of the answerers confused meanings. "Особо" ("особенно", "особенный") is not only means 'very', it also means 'different', "special".

Therefore, most literal translation is "for *specially* gifted".